# MySQL - Complex COUNT Query

Tags: mysql, sql, count, max

I have a table called user_scores as below:

```
id | af_id | uid | level | record_date
----------------------------------------
1  | 1.1   | 1   | 3     | 2012-01-01
2  | 1.1   | 1   | 4     | 2012-02-01
3  | 1.2   | 1   | 3     | 2012-01-01
4  | 1.2   | 1   | 5     | 2012-03-01
...
```

I have another table call user_info as below:

```
uid | forename | surname | gender 
-----------------------------------
1   | Homer    | Simpson | M
2   | Marge    | Simpson | F
3   | Bart     | Simpson | M
4   | Lisa     | Simpson | F
...
```

In user scores uid is the user id of a registered user on the system, af_id identifies a particular test a user submits.  A user scores a level between 1 - 5 for each test, which can be submitted every month.

My problem is I need to produce an analysis at the end of the year to COUNT the number of users that have achieved each level for a particular test.  The analysis is to show a gender split for male and female.

So for example an administrator would select test 1.1 and the system would generate stats based that would COUNT of the total MAX level achieved by each user in the year, with a gender split.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

-

I think I need to clarify myself a bit. Because a user can complete the test multiple times throughout the year, there will be multiple scores for the same test. The query should take the highest level achieved and include this in the count. An example result would be:

```
Male Results: 
level1 | level2 | level3 | level4 | level5 
------------------------------------------
2      | 5      | 10     | 8      | 1
```

Comment: Not a lot everything I try draws blanks.  I had thought of doing two separate queries for each gender.

Comment: I think you might run into problems if there are, say, no people of a particular gender who achieve a particular maximum level of a particular test.

Comment: Wow! this clarification was extremely necessary. This is now a whole different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `record_date` holds only dates (without time parts):

```
SELECT
  s.maxlevel,
  COUNT(NULLIF(gender, 'F')) AS M,
  COUNT(NULLIF(gender, 'M')) AS F
FROM user_info u
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      uid,
      MAX(level) AS maxlevel
    FROM user_scores
    WHERE record_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) DAY)
      AND af_id = '1.1'
    GROUP BY
      uid
  ) s ON s.uid = u.uid
GROUP BY
  s.maxlevel
```

That will show you only the maximum levels found in the `user_scores` table. If you have a `Levels` table where all possible levels (1 to 5) are listed, you could use that table to get a complete list of levels. If some levels are not present in the requested subset of data, the corresponding rows will show `0`s in both columns.

Here's the above script with minor changes to show the complete chart of levels:

```
SELECT
  l.level AS maxlevel,
  COUNT(NULLIF(gender, 'F')) AS M,
  COUNT(NULLIF(gender, 'M')) AS F
FROM user_info u
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      uid, MAX(level) AS maxlevel
    FROM user_scores
    WHERE record_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) DAY)
      AND af_id = '1.1'
    GROUP BY
      uid
  ) s ON s.uid = u.uid
  RIGHT JOIN Levels l ON s.maxlevel = l.level
GROUP BY
  l.level
```

Comment: +1 I particularly like your use of `NULLIF` here over a `CASE` statement.

Comment: Hi Andriy,

I have created a levels table to implement your second script.  This seems to produce the desired format, however, the count returned for each level is 0, which should have been a number.  Have implemented GarethD's example in the same manner with the same result

Comment: @AndrewMaughan: Um... Don't know what to say. Please have a look at [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a9b2/1), where I was playing with my script (using the tables shamelessly borrowed from GarethD's). You'll see that it works (at least, not all fields are 0). Maybe something is wrong (different) in the table structure(s) or something.

Comment: Problem solved. My column af_id was a float, not a varchar.  Once this was changed all worked as it should.  Thank you for your assistance this evening.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I am not certain I get exactly what you mean, but as always I'll have a go. As I understand it you want to know how many people from each gender reached each level in a certain year.

```
SELECT  MaxLevel, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ui.Gender = 'M' THEN 1 END) AS Males,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ui.Gender = 'F' THEN 1 END) AS Females
FROM    User_Info ui
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  MAX(Level) AS MaxLevel, 
                    UID
            FROM    User_Scores us
            WHERE   af_ID = '1.1'
            AND     YEAR(Record_Date) = 2012
            GROUP BY UID
        ) AS MaxUs
            ON MaxUs.uid = ui.UID
GROUP BY MaxLevel
```

I've put some sample data on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1de40/3) so you see if it is what you were after.

**EDIT**
To transpose the data so levels are along the top and Gender in the rows the following will work:

```
SELECT  Gender, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MaxLevel = 1 THEN 1 END) AS Level1,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MaxLevel = 2 THEN 1 END) AS Level2,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MaxLevel = 3 THEN 1 END) AS Level3,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MaxLevel = 4 THEN 1 END) AS Level4,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MaxLevel = 5 THEN 1 END) AS Level5
FROM    User_Info ui
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  MAX(Level) AS MaxLevel, 
                    UID
            FROM    User_Scores us
            WHERE   af_ID = '1.1'
            AND     YEAR(Record_Date) = 2012
            GROUP BY UID
        ) AS MaxUs
            ON MaxUs.uid = ui.UID
GROUP BY Gender
```

Note, that if there are ever more than 5 levels you will need to add more to the select statement, or start building dynamic SQL.

Comment: I've edited it, I've transposed your example because female and male are discrete, and I assume there can be any number of levels. However I've just seen Andriy M's answer and his is a slightly nicer way of doing the count.

Comment: Having seen the OP's sample output, I think your answer may appear more useful to him, because it shows how to use `CASE` with `COUNT`. (And it turns out he will need it, because his output is the pivoted version of mine and yours, where NULLIFs won't do.)

Answer (score 0):

EDITED based on your edit.

```
 select sum(if(a.gender="M",1,0)) Male_users, sum(if(a.gender="F",1,0)) Female_users
 from myTable a where 
    a.level = (select max(b.level) from myTable b where a.uid=b.uid) 
 group by af_id.
```

I typed this in a rush. But it should work or at least get you where you need to go. E.G. if you need to specify time frame, add that.

Comment: based on your edit I edit the code. I am actually in class. I will check back in a few hours, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what your looking for!

Show number of records group by userid and gender of the max score for af_id '1.1'.

```
select count(*), info.uid, info.gender, max(score.level)
from user_info as info 
join user_scores as score
  on info.uid = score.uid
where score.af_id = '1.1'
group by info.uid, info.gender;
```

Answer (score -2):

You need something like

```
SELECT
  uid,
  MAX(level)
WHERE
  record_date BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31'
  AND af_id='1.1'
GROUP BY uid
```

If you need the gender splits then depending on what stat you need per gender you can either add a JOIN on the user_info table into this query (to get the MAX per gender) to wrap this as a sub-query and JOIN on the whole thing.

Comment: This doesn't address the Q at all.  He wants a gender split, and a count, not a max value.

Comment: @JNK Not sure why the downvotes. This does address the question. Ok, the query only partially solved the problem but my explanation points to how the rest can be solved. I wasn't sure what stat he wanted per gender so left it open. Either because the question wasn't clear at the time, or because I was typing this late at night!